# Problem with css animation: position relative and value for left doesn't work apparently together

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's my problem:

I'm trying to animate a nav list (ul) and in my mind, I want to move it on click like that:

```js
$('#top-nav-more').click(function() {
  $('.hidden').toggleClass('hidden-click');
  $(this).find('img').toggleClass('rotate');
 });
```

```css
/** Top Nav **/
#top-nav {
 background: #e41a2e;
 padding:0 !important;
 display: inline-block;
 /*height:40px;*/
}

.top-nav-wrapper{
 max-width:1366px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

a.top-req-info{
 position: absolute;
    font-family: 'Daxline Light';
    font-size: 0.80rem;
    color: #FFF;
    background: #cd1729;
    padding: 10px 20px 11px 10px;
    /* float: left; */
}

a.top-req-info:hover, #top-nav-book a:hover, .hidden a:hover {
 text-decoration:none;
 color: #821b31;
}
a.top-req-info:hover, #top-nav-book:hover {
 background:  #821b31;
 color: white;
}
#top-nav-book:hover a {
 color: white;
}
#top-nav-more a, #top-nav-no a, #top-nav-book a, .hidden a {
 color: #FFF;
 font-size: 0.80rem;
}
.rotate {
 transform: rotate(180deg);
}
ul.top-nav-right{
 list-style: none;
 float: right;
 display: inline;
 margin: 7px 0;
}

ul.top-nav-right li{
 display:inline;
 padding: 8px 25px 8px;
}

li#top-nav-more{
 background: #cd1729;
}

#top-nav-more img{
 margin-right: 15px;
 transition: 0.3s;
}

.hidden {
 position: relative;
 left: 321px;
 display: none!important;
 transition:all 1s linear;
}
.hidden-click {
 transition:all 1s linear;
 position: relative;
 left: 0;
 display: inline!important;
}
ul .hidden:first-child {
 display: inline!important;
 left: 0;
}
.search-bar input {
 background-color: #821A31;
 color: #ffff;
 font-size: 35px;
 border: 0;
 margin: 0;
 height: 76px;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 0 80px;
 font-weight: 200;
 display: none;
}
.search-bar input:focus, .search-bar input:focus{
 outline: none;
}
.search-bar input.slide-down {
 display: block;
}
.search-bar input::placeholder {
 color: white;
}
.hover-bar {
 background: #821A31!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Top Navigation -- Red bar -->
  <div id="top-nav" class="container-fluid">
   <div class="top-nav-wrapper">
    
    <ul class="top-nav-right">
     
     <li class="hidden"><a href="">Health Care</a></li>
     <li class="hidden"><a href="">My Account</a></li>
     <li class="hidden"><a href="">Student Portal</a></li>
     <li id="top-nav-more"><a href="#">More</a></li>
     <li id="top-nav-no"><a href="#">Phone number</a></li>
     <li id="top-nav-book"><a href="#">Book a Tour</a></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Essentially, when you click more, the bar will change the position from some certain pixels to the left to 0 pixels on the left.

I added the transition effect to do it smoothly but for some reason, the effect happens right away. So technically it works but it doesn't work as I wish.

Something has to be wrong on my css transition. I read that it is possible to animate the position, so it is not a problem of position, it has to be something different. I've already use the property transition somewhere else in my code, so I have no clue of what is wrong, any idea?

Comment: You need absolute positioning.

Comment: It is already in an absolute position

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might get you close.  I imagine there might be more to the animation you're looking for.  It's hard to manipulate elements that are set to display none.  Visibility: hidden and position: absolute is an equivalent you can manipulate:

```
/** Top Nav **/
#top-nav {
    background: #e41a2e;
    padding:0 !important;
    display: inline-block;
    /*height:40px;*/
}

.top-nav-wrapper{
    max-width:1366px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

a.top-req-info{
    position: absolute;
    font-family: 'Daxline Light';
    font-size: 0.80rem;
    color: #FFF;
    background: #cd1729;
    padding: 10px 20px 11px 10px;
    /* float: left; */
}

a.top-req-info:hover, #top-nav-book a:hover, .hidden a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #821b31;
}
a.top-req-info:hover, #top-nav-book:hover {
    background:  #821b31;
    color: white;
}
#top-nav-book:hover a {
    color: white;
}
#top-nav-more a, #top-nav-no a, #top-nav-book a, .hidden a {
    color: #FFF;
    font-size: 0.80rem;
}
.rotate {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
ul.top-nav-right{
    list-style: none;
    float: right;
    display: inline;
    margin: 7px 0;
}

ul.top-nav-right li{
    display:inline;
    padding: 8px 25px 8px;
}

li#top-nav-more{
    background: #cd1729;
}

#top-nav-more img{
    margin-right: 15px;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.hidden {
    position: absolute;
    left: 321px;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition:all 1s linear;
}
.hidden-click {
    transition:all 1s linear;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    visibility: visible;
}
ul .hidden:first-child {
    display: inline!important;
    left: 0;
}
.search-bar input {
    background-color: #821A31;
    color: #ffff;
    font-size: 35px;
    border: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 76px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 80px;
    font-weight: 200;
    display: none;
}
.search-bar input:focus, .search-bar input:focus{
    outline: none;
}
.search-bar input.slide-down {
    display: block;
}
.search-bar input::placeholder {
    color: white;
}
.hover-bar {
    background: #821A31!important;
}
```

Working/semi-working example:
https://jsfiddle.net/qLpfynks/

Comment: It is actually a good solution, so the following question is kind of logic.. is it possible to animate a display: none to display block element?

Comment: @Matto You can't with CSS, but you can use jQuery .show, .hide and .toggle.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason is because you are switching from `display:none` to `display: inline`. CSS cannot transition `display` and so it will show the "transition" immediately.

To fix this and still achieve the desired effect change it to

```
.hidden {
position: relative;
left: 321px;
display: inline!important;
    opacity:0; /*makes it invisible*/
transition:all 1s linear;
    /*transition:left 1s linear*/
}
.hidden-click {
transition:all 1s linear;
    /*transition:left 1s linear*/
position: relative;
left: 0;
    opacity: 1; /*makes it visible*/
display: inline!important;
}
```

Note that if you use the specificier `all` for your transition you will see a fade in and out animation. If you don't want this, specify only `left` (see commented CSS code)